# ob_start() not replacing content

Tags: php

```
<?php
    ob_start(function($buffer){ 
          $buffer = preg_replace("/{%(data_.*?)%}/", '<?php echo $data[\'slot_$1\']; ?>', $buffer);
          $buffer = preg_replace("/{%menu_(.*?)%}/", '<?php echo insertNav($_data[\'slot_$1\']); ?>', $buffer);
          return $buffer;
    });
?>
```

Trying to use the preview code to replace content with php code.  Basically, it is for an editor similar to this one on stack overflow where if you type `** strong text **` = **strong text** except I'm using it to pull data from a database for a particular item.  I am using `{%data_#%}` to get the # and replace it with `$data['slot_#']` just for a reference on what I am doing with this.

If I replace `<?php echo $data[\'slot_$1\']; ?>` with 'Hello' it echoes out Hello.  So why isn't it echoing out the php code?

### EDIT

I replaced it with `$buffer = preg_replace("/{%(data_.*?)%}/", '$1', $buffer);` and it echoes out data_1.  It isn't getting the # value and placing it into the php code echoed out.  The echoed out code appears to be  `$data['slot_data_#]` instead of `$data['slot_#']`.  It is only supposed to get the number when typing in `{%data_#%}`

### EDIT 2

I finally got the number to echo out.  Turns out I had a `(` in the wrong spot.  Here is my new line: `$buffer = preg_replace("/{%data_(.*?)%}/", '<?php echo $data[\'slot_$1\']; ?>', $buffer);`.... however, it still is leaving everyhting blank.  I know that $1 is now echoing out the correct number, but when I put it into the php code, nothing gets echoed out on the page.  And I copied and pasted that php code directly in and replaced the number with $1 so that should be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over the past few days, I found that using ob_start() to return php code can only be done via eval() and that it is somewhat of an unsafe code as it leaves you open to php injections.  Thank you @revo

I have transitioned over and learned how to code a template engine and used a .tpl file so that users cannot put their own php code into the page and everything gets processed using a php page running in the background using functions (template engine). This prevented me from having to use an eval() code as @revo recommended that I stick away from using this without proper validation (which I'm not sure I want to even have to worry about the validation to be honest).

I wanted to inform everyone who viewed this question of what I learned and would suggest working with template engines & functions and avoid using the method I am recommending in my question.

Thank you @revo for working with me on a possible solution and keeping me informed of vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    ob_start(function($buffer){ 
          $buffer = preg_replace("/{%data_(.*?)%}/", '?><?php echo $data["slot_$1"]; ?><?php', $buffer);
          $buffer = preg_replace("/{%menu_(.*?)%}/", '?><?php echo insertNav($_data["slot_$1"]);?><?php', $buffer);
          return eval($buffer);
    });
```

PHP codes within `ob_start` are not executed in this way, you should work with an evil function: `eval()`

Comment: @kdjernigan It's known to be not safe if you don't have any validations on your inputs.

Comment: changed it to `$buffer = preg_replace("/{%data_(.*?)%}/", ' echo $data[\'slot_$1\']; ', $buffer); $buffer = preg_replace("/{%menu_(.*?)%}/", ' echo insertNav($data[\'slot_$1\']); ', $buffer);
return eval($buffer);` and now getting this error ... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/***/public_html/view.php(14) : eval()'d code on line 4

Comment: also, is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?  Just trying to create short code to pull from a database.  I know I have to use php to pull from database, but not sure if theres a better way than ob_start that will achieve my goal.

Comment: @kdjernigan well I don't know really how your codes are go to be, but this replacement can be done in the right place, after fetching data from DB?!

Comment: How do I add validation to protect this code?  Or, if you know a better option than this code....I'd love to hear about it.  I don't like the idea behind unsafe code, but at the same time, I don't know any other options to achieve this method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44482/discussion-between-kdjernigan-and-revo)